# Spring Android mocking with Robotium

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, robotium

I'm trying to use Robotium with my own project, but the problem is that it uses constantly spring for android to make REST calls. Just a few are network independent. I know that I should make mock objects or a mock server but I don't know how to specify to spring for android how to mock these calls

How should I mock them?

Thanks!

Comment: have you had any progress? I'm interested as well.